# NEC 14 wiring a remote / unfinished / garage with 120/240 circuits

Tags: wiring, garage

I have read the answers related to "how-to install code compliant" questions for wiring a remote/unfinished garage.  The answers all are based upon earlier dated NEC code books.

Has anything substantively changed under the bureaucratic umbrella the NEC 2014 code regs impose?

---

THANK YOU FOR IMPROVING FOCUS OF MY APPROACH...(Some light background)

- On a rural parcel, I am building a 40x40 concrete slab ag barn that by county local code doesn't require NEC 2014 compliance inspection outside of the plumbing & electrical systems.
- By site plan efficiency, one corner of that slab is closest (+/- 100') from  the Power Company's main power disconnect, and, therefore where I intend to set my 100 amp sub-panel for all barn circuits to home run to.
- That same corner of the barn is also only 40' from the septic system inlet so the toilet & the handsink I intend for the barn to have are logically wanting to be adjacently built/located.

1ST EDIT TO MY QUESTION:

If I locate the 100amp subpanel on that corner with inside of building access only, (read from the 5" higher concrete slab), is it code permissible I locate/build the other 3 walls of the bathroom lower/off the slab?  If it's floor is lower, but the bathroom would share a common wall with the subpanel,...does that construct bust any NEC 2014 insall/trade codes?

2ND EDIT/RESPONSES TO THE QUESTION & GENERATED COMMENTS:

We domicile on 45 acres on the plains E of Colorado Spgs.  I prior was 24 years a licensed B-2 GC in Nevada.  We separately have an active building permit with the regional building dept for work unrelated to my question.  Right or wrong, we have 2 consumer entitlement found under our local municipal.  1ST) As long as it's inspected & passes relevant UBC code, for every trade, by county/regional code only, it's permissible for the homeowner to do all of the work.

2ND)  Any structure being constructed for the use benefit of agriculture (RURAL BUILD LOCATIONS ONLY) isn't required to present itself for absolutely any inspections, so long as no electrical or plumbing phases are included in the build effort.

If any of/either electrical or plumbing phases are included in the Ag Building construct, they have to be installed up to the code that the prevailing municipality currently uses.  In Colo Springs, that's NEC 2014.

Because no CO is ever issued without everything being built/inspected/passed to the published UBC industry standard, the plumbing/electrical issues relevant to health & life safety are protected while not denying motivated "pudknockers" from doing their own work.

My barn/shop falls under such a qualified use entitlement exclusion.  I called/asked the electrical inspector for an informational site visit vis-a-vis the ag build exclusion with both electrical & plumbing phases present in the effort.  He said "I don't have the time to spoon feed you the code" & suggested that I google NEC 2014 code as it's applied to a "remote unfinished garage" and that's how I landed upon this forum's doorstep.

I've learned from each of those who generously responded here.  Thanks to one & all.  I'm indebted to this community & will try to give back appropriately.

Comment: This question is a bit broad.  If you search google for changes to the NEC, you should find a few reliable places that list and/or discuss the changes. Mike Holt usually posts a list of all the changes, which can be found [here in PDF format](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwienKnrorvVAhWI7CYKHbNSCogQFggmMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mikeholt.com%2Fdownload.php%3Ffile%3DPDF%2F2017_Code_Changes_Summary.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGGEHfVfLghzZ9FqiDqZ-UH6JlDVw)

Comment: You can also view a [free online version of the NEC](http://www.nfpa.org/codes-and-standards/all-codes-and-standards/list-of-codes-and-standards/detail?code=70), though you'll have to create an NFPA account.

Comment: Yes, a lot of things have changed. What is your specific question? If you ask a question with your proposed plan for wiring the garage and if it meets code, that would work.

Comment: Or edit this question, click the word "edit" which is at the end of your question just below the keyword buttons ("wiring" and "garage").

Comment: You seem quite confused about the way the various pieces that make up the overall building code system interact, and are pinning a lot of things on the NEC's head that Article 90 doesn't touch.  Is your jurisdiction adopting building codes for the first time?

Comment: You shouldn't completely change your question, after you've already received an answer. Your first question was too broad, your second question is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is: Yes, some things have changed.
The exact language from the 2014 National Electrical Code:

> **(G) Basements, Garages, and Accessory Buildings.** For a one-family dwelling, at least one receptacle outlet shall be installed in the areas specified in 210.s2(G)(1) through (3). These receptacles shall be in addition to receptacles re- quired for specific equipment.
>
> (1) Garages. In each attached garage and in each detached garage with electric power. The branch circuit supplying this receptacle(s) shall not supply outlets outside of the garage. At least one receptacle outlet shall be installed for each car space.

Edit: The paraphrased language I posted before was from a municipal licensing agency and was not the exact language. As pointed out, their language was somewhat misleading. The actual Code language clarifies that "The branch circuit supplying **this** receptacle(s) shall not supply outlets outside of the garage."

[Here is a more wordy explanation.](https://jadelearning.com/jadecc/courses/UNIVERSAL/NEC05.php?imDif=653.1)

To answer your edited question, no there is nothing in the Code preventing you from installing a panel close to a bathroom but you cannot locate the panel **in** the bathroom. The level of the floor is immaterial to the Code. If it fits the definition of a bathroom in the Code then you can't put a panel in that room or area.

Good luck and stay safe!

Comment: To note, if you have additional circuits in the garage (beyond those required for the mandatory minimum), those circuits can supply receptacles both inside of the garage and outside of the garage.

Comment: @statueuphemism -- note that in NEC 2017, a 20A garage receptacle SABC is required, but it can also supply outdoor receptacles.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel isn't an SABC a Small Appliance Branch Circuit?

Comment: @ArchonOSX -- indeed -- I use that term generically for 20A circuits that serve receptacles exclusively.